# Share files via mail app without requesting permission

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm getting the file Uri, then use it to build an intent and pass read permissions for that Uri:

```
      Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(MainActivity.this).setType("image/jpeg")
          .setStream(uri).getIntent();
      String sendTo[] = {"send_to_email@gmail.com"};
      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
      shareIntent.setData(uri);
      shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

The problem is that `shareIntent.setData(uri)` adds the Uri as a recipient in the "To" field along with email from `sendTo[]`.

This issue gets fixed by avoiding the `shareIntent.setData(uri)`, but according to [BABBQ talk about file sharing](https://youtu.be/C28pvd2plBA?t=19m55s), the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION will not work if the `setData(uri)` is not set.

How to avoid adding Uri passed in `.setData(uri)` as a recipient in the "To" field? Thanks!

Comment: If your minSdkVersion is 16 or higher you don't need to use `setData()`. The system will copy the URI to the Intent's ClipData which makes `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` work as expected without having to use `setData()`.

Comment: It's also worth filing a bug against the affected email client as it shouldn't even look at the 'data' part of the Intent for `ACTION_SEND` Intents.

Comment: Thanks, @cketti, I was building against minSdk 15.